# Throttling in Signal R clients on server side

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using hub on server side. Signal R client methods can be called many times in 1 seconds.Suppose client method is called 1000 times.But client is not able to handle these large number of requests. Is there any way to throttle the client methods on server side.So instead of calling 1000 times I will pass only 100 times per second. 
I have stumbled upon timer for my requirement.But it will take too much memory (CPU utilization). Is there any nice way to do it?

Comment: I would create a message buffer on the client side whose entries you then can easily process at the desired rate.

Comment: But this will put pressure on client side..which is not desirable

Comment: I don't quite get it... when you want less messages to be sent, you must decide which ones should be sent and which ones can be dropped. That totally depends on what you need. BTW: Updated information at 1000 Hertz  makes no sense at all in my eyes (except for putting them into a long list or chart), because your clients screens refresh much slower.

Comment: Thats what I need .. less messages to be sent to client... throttling them on the way..

Answer (score 0):

If the SignalR hub is not in a web farm or load balanced environment, then you could store the time that the last message was broadcast into the application memory cache (server side) and then check the time the last message was broadcast (from the cache) before broadcasting another message.  Do not send the message if one was already sent within X number of milliseconds.